# Debug bundled scripts in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

Need to render bundled scripts from one project into another project in MVC. Unable to use Scripts.Render since both are seperate projects. If I use `<script src="relative path of bundled script">` it works but I'm not able to debug any more. Is there a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

2 projects are in same solution? if so try to do file linking, then do bundle from link-files
will get you debug and production versions.

btw: any objective reason to have cross call for content files between projects?

Comment: Yep both are in the same solution. Can you please provide a sample code of file linking. The reason for seperate projects is that each project represents a User Interface. During maintenance phase if I need to change a particular UI then only that project could be modified and moved to production. That was my thinking .. Is there a better way ?

Comment: Placed all views into single project. That solves all issues.